# SQL Server table identity specification and composite key

Tags: sql-server, database, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

hi I have two basic tables one is company and the next one is items reationship between these two tables are 1 to M (1 company has many items associated with it and one item belongs to one company only )

```
Company = {companyid,companyname}
           _________
items = {itemid,itemname,companyid}
        _______          ---------
```

I have set itemid identity specification to YES and now the item ID gets increased 
if I have two companies id 1 & 2 A sample data table would show this

```
itemid   itemname    idcompany
-----    -------     ---------
1         car            1
2         bus            2
3         bike           1
4         motorcycle     2
```

My issue is when showing company specific data I get this

```
company 1
itemid   itemname    idcompany
-----    -------     ---------
1         car            1
3         bike           1

company 2
itemid   itemname    idcompany
-----    -------     ---------
2         bus            2
4         motorcycle     2
```

**how do I keep the item id sequential for each company ?**
Thank you

Comment: You should not attempt to _"keep id sequential"_ - this is not the PK purpose. Add row_number() to select statements or even generate this rn on client side.

Comment: is it okay if I add another column and check for max(itemid2) and increase  because every company will have its own id sequence on items, salesorders, invoices if I cant keep the PK sequential its best to show another ID which is unique isnt it ?

Comment: of course, there surely can be something like `sort_no`/`priority` column.

Comment: You could add a calculated column to keep the item id per company, based on the company id and general item id, or use `row_number() over(partition by idcompany order by itemid)` in your select statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**

What does "sequential" even mean?

**Suggestion**

The Sequence possibly could change based on the business question. For instance, does *sequence* always mean in the order in which the row was inserted into the table, or does it mean the time at which the item was added? Regardless, you may want to implement the concept of a sequence independent of how the data is stored. For instance, based on your need, you could do something like this (which gives you the sequence of each item by company, based solely on the `item_id` itself):

```
select *,
    itemsequence = row_number() over (
        partition by (idcompany)
        order by (itemid))
from items;
```

Hope this helps.